# a limit of recurrencive sequence with sine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

consider the sequence $s_1=\sin 1$, $s_2=\sin\sin 1$, $s_3=\sin\sin\sin 1$ etc.,  the recurrence relation is $s_0=1$, $s_{n+1}=\sin s_n$.

this sequence is bounded and decreasing, so convergent and it's easy to show that $s_n\to 0$.

Is $n^a\cdot s_n$ convergent to a positive real number for some $a>0$ ?

(it's my own question, I don't know the answer and have no idea for the solution)

Comment: This has been aked on the site before but know that the idea, in a nutshell, is to consider the sequence of general term $(s_n)^\beta$ for some fixed $\beta$. Since $\sin x=x-x^3/6+o(x^3)=x(1-x^2/6+o(x^2))$, one has $(s_{n+1})^\beta=(s_n)^\beta(1-\beta (s_n)^2/6+o((s_n)^2))$ hence $(s_{n+1})^\beta-(s_n)^\beta\sim-\beta (s_n)^{\beta+2}/6$ for every $\beta\ne0$, in particular, $(s_{n+1})^{-2}-(s_n)^{-2}\to1/3$ hence $(s_n)^{-2}\sim n/3$ and $\sqrt{n}s_n\to\sqrt3$.